# "What is dangerous is not the same as what appears so" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does

> What is dangerous is not the same as what appears so.

mean? Especially, the *'what appears so'* part. Does that phrase have a special meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is dangerous is not the same as what appears so

"So" can function as a [pro-form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form), which means it stands (or substitutes) for an element that can be understood from the context. In this case, it stands for the adjective that's mentioned in the previous statement (*dangerous*).

> What is dangerous is not the same as what appears (to be) **dangerous**.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! So this means that the sentence means that being dangerous and looking dangerous are two difcerent things?

Comment: @DannyHan You are welcome, yes. No special meaning at all :)

Comment: @DannyHan You are welcome again. But I recommend you read this [Not so fast!(when to accept an answer)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). There are many grammarians here, they could give you a more sastisfying answer, if happens *so*, feel free to unaccept mine :)